# Question about Lemma 2.2 in van der Vaart (1998)

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

I have a question about deriving Lemma 2.2.
I attached the picture showing the lemma.
The right bottom to left top is proof of showing (i) to (ii).
My question is how to derive inequalities of them.
How can I bound the absolute difference of expectations of some continuous functions?

Thank you.

[P.6 to 7 of van der Vaart (1998)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roBMz.jpg)

Comment: Just follow the proof. It is self-contained.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain how this inequality hold: $|E(f(X_n)) - E(f_\epsilon(X_n))| \le \epsilon + P(X_n \notin I)$ ?

Comment: $$
|E(f(X_n)-f_\epsilon(X_n))1\{X_n\in I\}|\le|E(f(X_n)-f_\epsilon(X_n))1\{X_n\in I\}|+|E(f(X_n)-f_\epsilon(X_n))1\{X_n\notin I\}| \le \epsilon + P(X_n \notin I)
$$